# Train/test split and leave-one-out

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I need to build and evaluate a classifier over 100 examples. There are reasons for which I need to use a leave-one-out cross validation approach, and I have a doubt on how I should proceed.

Which, among the 2 following options, is the correct one?

a) perform a LOO by creating 100 folds over 1-VS-99 and consider the average performance on the 100 folds as the performance for my classifier

b) split the 100 examples on 70 for training and 30 for test, then apply the LOO strategy only to the 70 training examples (with 1-VS-69 folds), and then evaluate the model by applying it on the 30 test examples

Comment: What is the purpose of the LOO on the training in the second case?

Comment: I was thinking to keep a set of examples just for testing purposes, completely separated from the training process. Similarly as suggested in this flow diagram on sklearn documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/_images/grid_search_cross_validation.png . Does it make sense?

Comment: If you have hyper-parameters to tune, yes.

Comment: so option b without the need of fine tuning hyper-paramters doesn't make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cross validation is commonly used for hyper-parameter (HP) tuning or having a more stable test performance estimate. If you're to tune some HPs in your algorithm, case (b) definitely makes sense, though I'd advise an outer CV for the test since dataset is small. But, if there is no HP to optimize and you only want to evaluate the test performance, case (a) is better (has less variance), especially in small dataset like yours, because test performance will not be affected by your test set choice.

Comment: What do you mean by outer CV? I also have a small dataset (20 samples) trying to solve a binary classification prediction problem that is moderately unbalanced(Class 1 = 8, Class 2 = 12). My understanding is that I have to use LOOCV because of the super small dataset but I am not sure if I should use it on whole dataset or train dataset. Help would be greatly appreciated. I'm hypertuning and more using TPOT an autoML algorithm that uses GAs to find best ML pipeline.

Comment: @AchilleasPavlou here outer CV is for performance eval, and inner CV is for model & feature selection. Read "nested CV" in the forum or other sources for better understanding. I think TPOT does the inner part for you (with the training fold), and you'll apply outer cv (i.e. use TPOT several times)